# Standard deviation of a computed response

Tags: standard-deviation, dependent-variable

I have the following,

1. mean values of 2 model parameters
2. corresponding standard deviations of those 2 parameters
3. correlation coefficient
4. a computed response
5. a measured response
6. standard deviation of the measured response

How can I get an equation of the standard deviation of the computed response with these information?
I only know that correlation coefficient is cov(x,y)/sigma_x*sigma_y

Comment: What is the equation for the computed response? How are you calculating it? I should think its std would be highly dependent on its formula.

Comment: The computed response does not have any equation. It just reads r(subscript c)

Comment: I don't see how you could possibly answer this question theoretically unless you know how the computed response is computed. Empirically, you can just use the sample standard deviation formula if you have data for the computed response.